# How to quickly solve simple linear congruence equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How to solve $97x \equiv 1 \mod 61$ in a quick way?

I tried to solve it in the Diophantine equation form $97x + 61y = 1$ by using Euclidean algorithm and got the sample result of  $x = 22$ and $y = 35$.

However, the calculation took me quite long to do it, even if I was highly concentrated it would still take me $5-7$ min to solve.

I want to ask whether we had any other way to quickly solve these kind of linear congruence equations?

Answer (score 3):

You can add and subtract in congruences just like normal equations.  You can reduce numbers to the range $0,1,\ldots,m-1$, where $m$ is the modulus.  Or reduce to a small negative number if that's easier.  You can also cancel a factor from the left and right hand sides, **provided** the factor you cancel is coprime to the modulus.  In the present case you could very quickly solve the congruence like this:
$$\eqalign{97x\equiv1\pmod{61}\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad 36x\equiv1\pmod{61}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad 36x\equiv-60\pmod{61}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad 3x\equiv-5\pmod{61}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad 3x\equiv-66\pmod{61}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x\equiv-22\pmod{61}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x\equiv39\pmod{61}\ .\cr}$$
The two cancellation steps have removed $12$ and $3$, each of which is coprime to $61$.

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 61\!:\ \dfrac{1}{97}\equiv\dfrac{1}{36}\equiv\left(\dfrac{1}6\right)^2\!\equiv\left(\dfrac{-60}6\right)^2\!\equiv(-10)^2\equiv 39$